# Why does the HTML5 DOCTYPE mess with my padding?

Tags: html, padding, doctype

I have an html5 page with a navbar. Completely scratch coded. I just recently added a doctype to the item, and now I’m getting extra space under my navbar. If I remove the doctype declaration, it goes back to normal. I have completely reset padding, margins, etc. on everything, and cut it down to the a small amount of code that illustrates the issue.

The page can be seen at http://hackthetruth.org/webdesign/broken

Does anyone know why declaring the doctype is messing with the height of a div?

Comment: 1. why are you starting your design without a doctype declaration? 2. i'd like to help, but i'm using FF and so get presented with a 'use webkit' message (which also appears to lack a doctype declaration).

Comment: I've opened things up to Firefox as well now and added a doctype to the browser page. I've still got the issue, and can't quote get it figured out. Since there is a known quantity of extra space, I have done a patch for my main site with a negative margin. What I am interested in is how I can fix this issue. it appears to be some sort of quirk in the rendering engines, because there should be no space after the <ul> element.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is an interesting and subtle, yet important consideration when using `inline-block`.

The short answer is: set `vertical-align` on your `ul` to anything other than `baseline`.

The reason this works is that inline-blocks are considered text, and thus are subjected to text-based properties such as line-height and vertical-align.

---

The longer answer is as follows:

The CSS3 specification goes in to some (perhaps confusing) depth around how the box model works. Here's a quote from the CSS3 box spec, in which I've highlighted the part that's relevant to this problem:

> 9.5. ‘Inline-block’ or floating, non-replaced elements
>
> ... The used value of `height` is the computed value,
>   unless that is ‘auto’, when the used value is defined by “‘Auto’
>   heights for flow roots.”

Let's check what the auto heights for flow roots are:

> 9.10. ‘Auto’ heights for flow roots
>
> In certain cases (see the preceding sections), the height of an
>   element is computed as follows:
>
> - If it only has inline-level children, the height is the distance between the top of the topmost line box and the bottom of the
>     bottommost line box.
>
> ...

The line box parts are of interest. What this effectively implies is that anything set to display as inline-block is subject to the implicit box layouts that plain text uses.

You might be able to guess now why setting `vertical-align` fixes this problem, but let's continue tracing this problem through the spec.

The [`line-box`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#line-box) definition is a little lacklustre, and the example in [section 4.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#block-level0) is only marginally helpful.

Let's go back to the CSS 2.1 spec, which does a far nicer job at [explaining line boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#line-box):

> The rectangular area that contains the boxes that form a line is called a line box ... [its height] is determined by the rules given in the section on line height calculations.

From this explanation, we see that the `line-height` and `vertical-align` properties have something to do with how the heights (of line boxes, thus inline-block elements) are calculated. Reading the [calculations of line-height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height) almost make it clear:

> ...In case [line boxes] are aligned 'top' or 'bottom', they must be aligned so as to minimize the line box height.

So our inline-block element's height is being affected by its implicit line box's height calculations, which are in turn subject to these vertical-alignment calculations.

So it would seem that when we don't use baseline as a vertical-align for an inline-block, the box's implicit line box will shrink to the smallest size it can.

Confusing? ...Yeah. Just jump back to the shorter answer :)

Comment: Alright, after messing around with the various possible values for `vertical-align` I am satisfied that you are entirely correct. You are only slightly off: in this specific case, `top`, `text-top`, `middle`, `bottom`, `text-bottom`, and `sub` result in the desired behavior, while the three remaining values (`height` in `px` or `%` and `baseline`) results in some other variety of wrong. Messing around with some `height` values (in `px`) I have seen that someone might conceivably use them as a form of variable top/bottom padding, but that would be silly. :)

Comment: I was having this problem with the headers with images in my accordion view.  Adding .ui-accordion-header { margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0; } to my css file fixed the problem.  line-height: 0; was the critical setting.

Answer (score 45):

I had the same problem with one of my sites.
i found this answer [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3132/how-to-stop-gmail-from-adding-a-margin-to-your-images/):

*"With an HTML5 doctype, images receive what seems to be the line-height attribute which text normally gets, and thus you get a “margin” underneath them. You can either set them to display:block or line-height:0, although I haven’t tested the latter enough to be sure it’s a good fix."*

I applied the `line-height:0` to the `<div>` which contained the navigation images. It did the trick for me.

Comment: This is the actual answer, much better then the "go read about the box model" answer at +8 :)

Comment: This would be the answer, but *there are no images here*. So, unless this same sillyness can get applied to `<li>`s, it's something else at work.

Comment: Note that I set `line-height: 0;` to the _parent_ div element rather than the image inside.  I had tried `#parent img { line-height: 0; }` and that did _not_ work.  `#parent { line-height: 0; }` was the solution!

Answer (score 9):

It's because the DOCTYPE changes the rendering mode to Standards Compliance Mode. Specifically, this means you're using the W3C Box Model now which computes width/height for block elements differently than quirks mode.

Read more [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html), [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html), and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Comment: Yes, I get that much, but I have forced all the margins/paddings on everything to 0/whatever they should be. I’m not new to the whole web thing, just a little confused as to why I’m getting extra space on ONE div because of the box-model

Alrighty, but why the heck does that change the height?

Comment: I’m still wondering why the heck this has any affect on the HEIGHT, when I only padded the width.

Comment: @Dakota are you talking about why "monkey" is 26px? I guess you expect it to be 24px or something?

Comment: I assumed that #monkey would have the same height as it's child <ul>, but I am wrong. There's 4 extra pixels in there, ala the Box Model.

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

css:

```
html * { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when upgrading a XHTML4 website to HTML5.  I had lots of these:

```
<a><img></a>
```

Which ended up with the magical extra padding around the images.  For me the solution was simple -- add this css:

```
img { vertical-align: top; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `display: inline-block` due to the IE7 issues, so I'm not familiar with its quirks. It seems like it's unnecessary to apply it to `ul#pagetab` in your situation, since it's not surrounded by inline elements. I would just convert it to a regular block element. Moreover, since it contains floated elements that do not need float beside some inline elements, I would just give `ul#pagetab` a real height via `display: block; overflow: hidden;`.

This appears to resolve all your issues (which I can't account for in detail) and provides stylistically more appropriate styles.

Answer (score -1):

Mate you have 2 stray `</div>` tags in that page. On lines 32 and 34. Delete and retry. See if that fixes it.

Answer (score -3):

wow. @matt is right (not in this case) and that's general knowledge, but you're all wrong.

dude look @ your css, you have

## pagetab {background-color: #ff2d00; padding: 0px 4px; margin: 0; display: inline-block;}

## pagetab ul {list-style: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 4px; display: block;}

for  .....

so that second declaration is on nested ul that occur in #pagetab. you dont have any of those.

i took the ul off the declaration so they're on the correct element. now your css has 2 styles that match for both (and are also called in your universal selector (fyi, which goes above your body{} declaration)) so thats 3 styles....overkill dude. moreover, the ones not matching, you set it to display:inline-block and then reset it to block...i'm lost in this logic.

SO
take your example. change two pagetab styles to this

## pagetab {

```
background-color: #ff2d00;
padding: 0px 4px;
margin: 0;
```

}

## pagetab {

```
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px 4px;
display: block;
```

}

save it. now strip  off it, save that as #2. in FF3.6 on 7 they are the same.

if you would use the validators that are provided specifically for solving/preventing issues like this, as well as qa tools (specifically here i'm talking about the dust-me selectors bookmarklet) you would resolved this in not time.

back to web standards, gen ed css: *{} is universal, so as long as another declaration doesn't override *'s specificity, it will always work.
in english, if you declare *{margin:0; padding:0; border:none} at the top of your page, you don't have to put margin:0; padding:0; on every single element. you already have.

web standards, they'll save your life.

Comment: While I notice that your answer is correct for my original example, I made a bunch of changes to make the example even clearer. You're right, my CSS is completely stupid, but it was written when I knew almost nothing about web design/development and I haven't yet had the chance to clean it all up. If you look at the current example, you'll see what I mean. *Your answer, however, doesn't address the 4 pixel issue I was actually asking about.*

Comment: i lIKe ReaDin somethings wheR**E** pepl TOOk the tim to `for`mat anD Type *prop*erle

Comment: @steve credit for having the balls for putting your name on that. still have yet to see this mythical style format guidelines trolls like you leave. you === the awesome

Comment: @albert - cheers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers