# HTML5 body spacing issue

Tags: css, html

I cannot seem to remove the spacing between the top of the page and the `<div>` in this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #container{
            background-color: #808080;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="inner-container">
            <h3>Index</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have narrowed it down to this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

It seems removing this aligns the `<div>` to the top of the page. I can't see a way in CSS to achieve the same thing.

Comment: probably this would help: [Why does the HTML5 DOCTYPE mess with my padding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003051/why-does-the-html5-doctype-mess-with-my-padding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the margin from your `<h3>` as well

```
h3 { margin-top: 0 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hw4zq/)

Comment: Argh! I've been looking at the html/body elements in Chrome tools, I didn't think the margin on the h3 would cause this... d'oh!

Comment: You are a genius / lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

Margins collapse into each other.

The top margin of `html` (0), `body` (0), `#container` (0), and `h3` (not 0) merge into a combined non-zero top margin between the first content and the edge of the window.

Set `h3 { margin-top: 0 }` to remove it.

(Although you should start your document with a heading (`h1`) not a sub-sub-heading (`h3`).)

Answer (score 0):

Actually [Default Margin Of H1 to H6](http://www.htmlcssdeveloper.com/tutorial/advanced-html-css/what-is-the-default-margin-of-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-h6.html) is the problem you are facing so overriding this value will solve your problem.

```
h3 { margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra Info:

You also might want to look into using a [CSS reset script](http://www.cssreset.com/) before starting a project so you don't have to worry about little things like this.

Comment: I am using HTML5 Boilerplate which uses Normalise.css already, I excluded it in the samples to help narrow down my problem.